# Как перехватить исключение

Tags: c++, исключения, деструктор

Почему данный код не ловит исключение?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:

public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        throw 1;
        std::cout << "A::~A(int)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* p = nullptr;

    try
    {
        p = new A();
        delete p;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "catch(...)" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то в деструкторах генерировать исключения категорически не рекомендуется!

Comment: и все же код не работает, почему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выбрасывать исключение из деструктора не рекомендуется и на это есть ряд причин.

- это может привести к утечкам памяти,
- невозможно обеспечить какие-либо гарантии безопасности,
- исключение из деструктора может вылететь во время раскрутки стека, что приведет к разным последствия в зависимости от объекта.

Посмотрим на Ваш код.

```
delete p;
```

Как известно, сначала `delete-expression` вызывает деструктор и затем освобождает память. Если деструктор выбрасывает исключение, то до освобождения памяти дело уже не дойдет и это приведет к утечке.

При реализации, например, контейнеров, невозможно обеспечить какие-либо гарантии относительно безопасности исключений. Например:

```
vector.push_back();//Вектор был не пуст
```

Допустим, произошло выделение памяти. Значит старые элементы копируются в новую область памяти. Если копирование прошло успешно, а при уничтожении старых объектов вылетело исключение, то мы получим часть неуничтоженных объектов и утечку памяти. Если же при копировании вылетело исключение и вектор попытается уничтожить уже сконструированные объекты, а при их уничтожении вылетит исключение, то получим ту же утечку, плюс дальше "полетит" уже другое исключение.

Если исключение вылетает из деструктора автоматического объекта во время раскрутки стека, то, в соответствии со стандартом, это приводит к вызову `std::terminate`

> 15.2 Constructors and destructors
>
> 3. The process of calling destructors for automatic objects constructed on the path from a try block to a throw-expression is
>      called “stack unwinding.” [Note: **If a destructor called during stack
>      unwinding exits with an exception, terminate is called (15.5.1). So
>      destructors should generally catch exceptions and not let them
>      propagate out of the destructor.** —end note]

Это цитата из C++03, но в последующих стандартах поведение не поменялось.

Начиная с C++11 все деструкторы по-умолчанию имеют спецификацию исключений `noexcept`. При нарушении этой спецификации вызывается `std::terminate`:

> Whenever an exception is thrown and the search for a handler (15.3)
>   encounters the outermost block of a function with an exception-specification that does not allow the exception, then,
>
> — if the exception-specification is a dynamic-exception-specification, the function std::unexpected() is called (15.5.2),
>
> — otherwise, the function std::terminate() is called (15.5.1).

То есть, начиная с C++11 любое исключение, покинувшее деструктор, приводит к вызову `std::terminate` и аварийному завершению программы, тем самым, как минимум, обеспечивая единое поведение и возможность предоставления каких-либо гарантий.
Деструктору возможно указать другую спецификацию исключений:

```
~A() noexcept(false) { /*...*/ }
```

Но при этом, если вылетит исключение, мы получим все проблемы указанные выше.

Итого: исключение, покинувшее деструктор создает много проблем, и не дает никакой пользы, поэтому общая рекомендация - никогда не позволять исключениям покидать деструктор.

Answer (score 7):

Вообще-то в деструкторах генерировать исключения категорически не рекомендуется. Как я понимаю (на конкретное место в стандарте не укажу) - фактически деструкторы объявлены как `noexcept` - а значит, при генерации в них исключения будет вызван `terminate`.

Вот, выполните [этот код](https://ideone.com/hqwAfO):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class A
{
private:

public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        throw 1;
        std::cout << "A::~A(int)" << std::endl;
    }
};



int main()
{

    std::set_terminate([](){ std::cout << "terminate called\n"; exit(1);});

    A* p = nullptr;

    try
    {
        p = new A();
        delete p;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "catch(...)" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Как видите, вызывается `terminate` - как результат генерации исключения там, где его быть не должно.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Значит правило 8 Майерса устарело?

Comment: Напомните, pls. А заодно - *когда* оно было написано.

Comment: Правило 8: Не позволяйте исключениям покидать
деструкторы 2005

Comment: Почему же устарело? Совершенно верное правило. Именно это я и написал в самом начале - "*в деструкторах генерировать исключения категорически не рекомендуется*".

Comment: @StanislavPetrov если хотите выбросить исключение, то `~A() noexcept(false) { /*...*/ }`, но, как уже написали, это не очень хорошая идея

Comment: Вызов деструкторов нужно обеспечить, деструкторы должны  завершить свою работу корректно, а не генерировать исключение.  Вы(компилятор)  же завершите (terminate)  со мной(программист)  разговор(программу),  когда я скажу: "если вы выполните мое условие(генерация исключения),   я могу сделать так,(обработка исключения )  что вы будете жить вечно (тело catch)".  Так что все логично...

Comment: Кто минусует - если ответ неверный (все мы можем ошибаться) - то будьте последовательны, укажите, в чем ошибка, чтоб была польза людям. А кой смысл просто так минусы ставить? Ну, или дайте свой ответ. А так - ни другого ответа, ни уточнения...

Comment: Всё правильно, исключения не должны покидать деструктор. Это значит, что ловить исключение нужно _внутри_ деструктора.

Comment: Почему это так: дело в том, что если у вас внутри блока происходит исключение, то поток выполнения вылетает из этого блока и выполняет все деструкторы локальных объектов. Если один из деструкторов сам по себе бросает исключение, какое из исключений должно лететь дальше?

Comment: @VladD никакое. Если автоматический объект выбрасывает исключение во время раскрутки стека, то будет вызван std::terminate. А вот если исключение выбросит не автоматический объект, то исключение будет заменено на новое.

Comment: Мне вот стало интересно, а что будет с той памятью что была выделена процессом во время работы, т.е. до выброса исключения в деструкторе, перед termanate? Менеджер памяти то не знает что ее можно вновь использовать?

Comment: @Yami если система умеет чистить за процессами, то после завершения процесса, ресурсы, которые он не освободил, система сама прихлопнет.

Comment: @Croessmah: В современных ОС система после смерти процесса подчищает за ним всё, что может, т. к нет никакой гарантии, что процесс чистит за собой. Но всякие штуки типа созданных файлов, конечно, остаются.

Comment: @VladD поэтому я и написал "если система умеет".

Comment: @Croessmah: Я к тому, что мне трудно вспомнить систему, которая таког не делает. Вроде бы даже DOS уже умела.

Comment: @VladD если не пометить память как резидентную :)